# xcode/clang: clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fcheck-new'

Tags: xcode, gcc, warnings, clang

As title:

I'm constantly getting this warning that flooded out my screen in Xcode4 for the -fcheck-new options that I use.

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fcheck-new'
```

Is it that clang does not support this gcc compiler option??? How can I get rid of the warnings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This warning can be silenced by adding the flag `-Qunused-arguments`

It's a warning because clang does not support the `-fcheck-new` argument.

Comment: You could also *remove* the bad flag.

Comment: For those of you who got these warnings when using Clang in conjunction with ccache, find more particulars here: http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2011/05/ccache-and-clang.html

Comment: For callbacks, it may not be possible to remove the unused flag.  Is there an equivalent to gcc's __attribute((__unused__)) ?

Comment: @CarlNorum not always you can remove the flag [example](http://codeengine.org/how-do-i-xcodebuild-a-static-library-with-bitcode-enabled/)

Comment: @ArtoBendiken Thanks very much - your link was just what I needed.  For those running Cygwin x64, as of writing, the packaged ccache does not include the [bugfix](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8118).  Therefore, you have to build ccache from source to get rid of the warnings.